# Transformations of curvilinear coordinate systems

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors, curvilinear-coordinates

I'm reading a book covering multiple topics in mathematics and physics. There's a chapter on tensors that had a very curious statement. It says "all curvilinear coordinate systems can relate to each other by some sort of rotation or series of rotations." I don't know what that precisely means. Does it mean that any curvilinear coordinate system can be transformed into any other one by rotations? It's not obvious to me that that is indeed the case. And if so, can we formally show that this is in fact the case?
PS: The book is called Covariant Physics: From classical mechanics to general relativity and beyond.

Comment: that "some sort" of rotations are called coordinates' changes

Comment: Doesn't seem quite right to me. Are you sure those are the words the author used?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, those are the author's exact words